# Zero Lyapunov exponent

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-exponents

Given a linear non autonomous dynamical system in two dimensions $x_{n+1}=A_{n}x_{n}$ started at $x_0\neq0$, $A_n\longrightarrow A$ invertible, assume it has zero Lyapunov exponent for all $x_0$, i.e. $\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\log\Vert x_n \Vert/n=0$. Is this enough to conclude that the system is not convergent when started at any of these $x_0$?

Comment: I don't think $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(\|x_n\|)/n$ is a Lyapunov exponent.

Comment: It is limsup in general but I have a system where the limsup is actually a limit and always 0 for any initial condition. See the first couple of pages of https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82587476.pdf for definitions

Comment: You can take for example $x_n=n$.